# Why is my CSS not getting applied to react components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am importing a CSS file in one of my components and applying a style to `list-group-item` how ever this style is not showing. My code is as follows and the full project can be found [here](https://github.com/int-a/contacts/tree/add-style)

styles.css:

```
.list-group-item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: red;
    outline-width: medium;
}
```

ContactList.jsx (component containing the element to be styled):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import selectContact from '../actions/action_select_contact'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import '../styles.css';

class ContactList extends Component {
  renderList() {
    return this.props.contacts.map((contact) => {
      return (
        <li
          key={contact.phone}
          onClick={() => this.props.selectContact(contact)}
          className='list-group-item'>{contact.firstName} {contact.lastName}</li>
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className = 'list-group col-sm-4'>
        {this.renderList()}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    contacts: state.contacts
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ selectContact: selectContact }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContactList)
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './client/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { 
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
          }
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'css-loader',
      query: {
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      }
    }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  devtool:"#eval-source-map"
};
```

Comment: A couple suggestions: (1) Check to be sure that _style.css_ is loaded on the client and doesn't contain any errors (i.e. 404 not found) from the dev tools, (2) Check the dev tools to see if the styles are being applied but overwritten by: (a) a later class declaration of the same name or, (b) an inline style...

Comment: you should try `styled-components`

Comment: @War10ck I do not see my styles getting loaded on the client, but I think part of my issue/complication is that I am serving my app (bundle.js) via an express endpoint, my "front-end" is a very simple html file that loads my bunlde.js in it's body.

Comment: was your issue resolved? if yes can you share the answer here